# How to remove square brackets for each item from a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Excel has a list of numbers, I am expecting  to see something like this:

```
[110652450, 5309154]
```

However I see something like this:

```
[[110652450], [5309154]]
```

I tried `newtest = [x[:-1] for x in df]` suggested on a similar question but that just removes my numbers and keeps the braquets

```html
df = pd.read_excel(filename.xlsx",sheetname='Sheet1')


df = df.values.tolist()

print(df)
```

Comment: You seem to think that `[[110652450], [5309154]] ` is a string but as far as I can see it's a multidimensional list. You have to access it by index. so `x[0]` would give you `[110652450], [5309154]` and `x[0][0]` will return `110652450`.

Comment: I suggest reading up a bit more on how to work with lists and other data types in Python.

Comment: @malan It doesn't seem that OP is trying to treat this list as a string (he even uses the word "list" in the title of the question). Where does he imply that `df` is a string?

Comment: @Joel, perhaps you're correct, but by accessing a slice of as though he was trimming off the brackets (though if he were doing that he would have written `x[1:-1]`) it just seemed to me, on an intuitive basis, that he was understanding the list of lists to be a string formatted with external brackets.

Comment: @Joel, I believe my initial comment was even incorrect. `x[0]` would result in `[110652450]` as the list is a list of single item lists and not a list of two-item lists.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't quite get your question, but you seem to be looking for something like this?

```
df = [[110652450], [5309154]]
newest = [i[0] for i in df]
print(newest)
>> [110652450,5309154]
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorted :)

Answer (score 2):

[numpy.squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) might be the preferred method to do this. Call `np.squeeze(a)` for the array that you wish to flatten. np.squeeze should be much faster than a list comprehension such as `[e[0] for e in a]`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
newtest = [x[0] for x in df]
```

you need to access  the first element of the list and use that instead of the whole list

Answer (score 0):

You have lists of one element. `x[:-1]` returns the list without the last element, so just an empty list. Instead, do `[x[0] for x in df]` or `[x for x, in df]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to remove the square brackets:

```
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx", sheetname="Sheet1")
df = df.values.tolist()
df = [x[0] for x in df]
print(df)
```

This works because every element in `df` is a list containing one item.